# Destroying after save if association is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I destroy a `Product` if it doesn't belong to a `Store` `after_save`?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :name, :product_store
  belongs_to :store
  attr_reader :product_store

  # I need this to do also "p.product_store.blank?"
  after_save { |p| p.destroy if p.name.blank? && p.price.blank? }

  def product_store=(id) # using Jquery TokenInput so only needed this.
    self.store_id = id
  end
end
```

I've tried a couple of different approaches like:

```
after_save { |p| p.destroy if p.name.blank? && p.price.blank? && p.product_store.blank? }
after_save { |p| p.destroy if p.name.blank? && p.price.blank? && p.store.id.blank? }
after_save { |p| p.destroy if p.name.blank? && p.price.blank? && p.store_id.blank? }
after_save { |p| p.destroy if p.name.blank? && p.price.blank? && p.store.blank? }
```

But these didn't work so I ask for your help on how it would be done?

---

Here is my form and controller: https://gist.github.com/1472629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about use ActiveModel::Validations?
you don't want to save record if some attribute not filled.so you need validation.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :price, :store_id
end
```

---

Edit:

your code looks want to create muti products use common attributes.
may be params like this:

```
{"products" => {:1 => {:name => "good", :desc => "sss"}}, {:2 => {:name => "good", :desc => "tt"}}, "product" => {:price => "10"} }
```

controller
    def create_multiple
      @products = params[:products].values.collect do |up|
        Product.new(up.merge(params[:product]))
      end
      if @products.each(&:save)
        redirect_to :back, :notice => "Success!"
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

Validation do not need change. but the form will a bit complicate.

```
form_tag "/products" do
  %p
   = text_field_tag "product[price]", @products.first.price
   = @products.first.errors[:price]

  - @products.each_with_index do |product, idx|
     = text_field_tag "products[#{idx}][name]", product.name
     = product.errors[:name]

  = submit_tag :submit
```

the code is simple, you can enhance the view yourself.

Comment: I can't use validations as I want them to be used, which is to only validate the Products that are somewhat filled out. It should destroy the Products that are left blank entirely.I posted my controller let you know what I am talking about. Do you know how to validate in this way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with haml. My form is similar though, check out my gist: https://gist.github.com/1472629

Answer (score 2):

This seems more like a validation issue. If it's invalid without a `Store`, then you shouldn't save it to the DB without a `Store` reference at all.

If you want to destroy the `Product` you should do that directly, rather than saving a nil reference to a store, trying to catch that, and then destroying it as a result.

By trying to destroy a record when its association is incorrect, you're essentially saying, "This in an invalid state, and shouldn't be in the database in the first place."

Comment: The reason I am not using validations is because I can't get it to work the way I need to. Check out my edit, my form/controller allows the creation of multiple products at the same time but all Products don't need to be filled out. What I need is to validate the products which are partially pr partially filled out. The products that aren't touched on the form shouldn't be saved at all. Since I couldn't get the validations working I resorted to this method.

Comment: Try nested models in forms ( http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 ) - this will make it so only the products that are filled out get submitted for creation. In this case your form would actually be for the Store, and the nested model would be the new Products. This is the way to solve this sort of issue, and utilize validations similarly to how blade has specified them in his answer.

Comment: I couldn't do the nested form because the way I have my fields. I allow the user to choose a Store like a category. So it would have to be a Store form which doesn't create a new Store at all. I hope that made sense. I posted my form and controller in a gist here:https://gist.github.com/1472629

Comment: I see. I still don't quite follow the data submission flow though. Regardless of the specific form setup, if someone doesn't select a store (on purpose, or by accident) that's still an invalid record. Shouldn't you flag that in the UI as "Hey, please select a store?" or is it intentional that you allow them not to select a store in some cases? I can't see why you would if you are **never saving products that don't have a store ID**, why it would ever be allowed. Saving them to the DB, just to delete them seems like extra work with you could throw a validation error.

Comment: Looking at your controller code, if you really want to take the approach that you're on, then (1) put in the model validation that blade has suggested, and (2) in the controller, before making the call to `create`, put a conditional in to check if there is a `Store` specified for the `Product` you're about to save, and if not then **don't save that specific Product** to the DB - just skip it. There's no point in trying to do this via a callback if you can prevent it being saved in the first place.

Comment: It's totally possible that I'm missing something in the code somewhere, but your situation doesn't seem unique enough to need a custom solution.

Comment: Users always have to select a store. The reason for destroying products with blanks fields is because the full form (all 3 products) isn't always going to be filled out so I want to only validate the ones which are filled out but if a user forgot a field on another product it also would throw an error for that one as well. That's the conclusion I am trying to get at. If I just add validations to the model and use `create!` in the controller, it will throw an error for a product that the user didn't even want to fill out in the first place. To counter I destroy blank fields of products.